# ZF2 TableGateway select() returns rows but values are empty

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZendFramework2 and try to build a simple CRUD application but I already have problems with the overview of books coming from the database.

In my index view I loop through the returned books array which has a count of 7 (8 rows) But the values are empty, except the id field which contains the author (??). Pretty weird.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace BookList\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use BookList\Form\BookForm;
use BookList\Model\Book;

class BookController extends AbstractActionController {

protected $bookTable;

public function indexAction() {
    return new ViewModel(array(
            'books' => $this->getBookTable()->fetchAll()
    ));
}// ...
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace BookList\Model;
class Book {
    public $id;


    public $title;
    public $author;

    public function exchangeArray($data) {
        $this->id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->id = (!empty($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
        $this->id = (!empty($data['author'])) ? $data['author'] : null;
    }

}
```

BookTable:

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class BookTable {

    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }//...
```

Index.phtml:

```
<?php foreach ($books as $book) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($book->title); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($book->author); ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url('book', array('action' => 'edit', 'id' => $book->id))?>">Edit</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url('book', array('action' => 'delete', 'id' => $book->id))?>">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

Module.php

```
..//
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
                'factories' => array(
                        'BookList\Model\BookTable' => function($sm) {
                            $tableGateway = $sm->get('BookTableGateway');
                            $table = new BookTable($tableGateway);
                            return $table;
                        },
                        'BookTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Book());
                            return new TableGateway('book', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                        }
                ),
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your Model. In `exchangeArray()` you're only ever setting the `id` field. So because the last line is for author, that's what `id` is getting set as.

Try this:

```
public function exchangeArray($data) {
    $this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->title  = (!empty($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
    $this->author = (!empty($data['author'])) ? $data['author'] : null;
}
```